# Scheme (DrRacket) substitute add1 with (+ x 1) or with lambda

Tags: scheme, racket

I am making this Exercises from this page 
http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Solutions/natnum-list.html

In this code

```
(define (depth a-dl
(cond
[(symbol? a-dl) 0]
[else (add1 (depth (first a-dl)))]))
```

We use add1 predefined function which means (+ x 1), I want to swap add1 with (+ x 1) or with lambda. Is it possible? if yes how?

Butt I want not write so outside the function.

```
(define (add1 x) 
        (+ x 1))
```

or so

```
(define add1 
(lambda (x)
    (+ x 1)))
```

Comment: You can  always replace one function with another that does the same or substitute the entire call with the expression that does the same. What do you mean by how?

Comment: I mean for this code segment  <pre>(add1 (depth (first  a-dl)) <code> I can't use  <pre>( ((+ a-dl 1) (depth (first  a-dl)) <code>

Comment: No you either replace `(add1 (depth...))` with `((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (depth...)) ` or replace the whole call `(+ (depth...) 1)`. These are true refactorings of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add1` can *not* mean `(+ x 1)`, because  there's no `x` in `add1`.

`(add1 x)` *can* mean `(+ x 1)` if it so defined.

To make it have this meaning, we'd define it as

```
(define (add1 x)
        (+  1 x))
```

or equivalently as

```
(define  add1
     (lambda (x)
        (+  1 x)))
```

this means that wherever `add1` appears, `(lambda (x) (+ 1 x))` can appear instead, with the same effect.

Of course, writing

```
( (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) ....Y.... )
```

is the same as writing

```
(              + 1     ....Y.... )
```

Comment: can we integrate this lambda function what do you wrote  with my function "depth" from above. aproximately so <pre>(define (depth a-dl ( lambda .......<code>

Comment: whenever you want to write `( add1 ....)` just put  `(lambda (x) (+ 1 x))` instead of `add1` in that piece of code. delete the 4 characters a d d 1 and put the other thing instead.

Comment: I do not understand with lambda but to swap add1 with + 1 it is easy I wrote so [else (+ (depth (first  a-dl)) 1)]))

Comment: correct! this will also work. the two ways are equivalent. with the simple `lambda` definitions it is easy to see, with more complex code this is more involved. the process is known as beta-reduction. you can look it up in Wikipedia or something.